# Default Conda Environments Stored in .conda Folder

Tags: conda, miniconda

I'm not sure if I just installed Miniconda incorrectly, but for some reason my default environment directory is in my C:\Users\username\.conda\envs folder. After having searched for a little while, it seems everyone else has their environments in a different folder, often in a folder called C:\Users\username\miniconda\envs, which confuses me. In fact, at some point I even saw that .conda was a deprecated folder name for Unix based systems, and I'm on a Windows machine. Am I just terrible at searching or did I do something very wrong with I installed Miniconda?

Answer (score 2):

This would be expected behavior if you

1. Installed Miniconda with elevated privileges. (Not recommended)
2. Created environments as a non-admin user.

Miniconda installations have two default locations where named environments go. The first is under `miniconda3/envs` and the second is `~/.conda/envs`. Conda defaults to trying to use the former, but if it is not writable, it will use the latter. There is nothing wrong with this *per se*, and this makes total sense for *multi-user installs*.

However, if you are the end user installing Miniconda, you're better off not installing as admin.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I'm honestly confused about the difference between user installs and multi-user installs. For example, I think my Python 3.9 installation is in my ProgramData folder, would that be considered a multi-user install? Should I reinstall miniconda without elevated privileges? I assume that would require me to create all of my envs over again, but I'm alright with that if it'd save me trouble in the future. Would there likely be a lot of lingering files that I'd need to clear or does uninstalling miniconda deal with that?

Comment: @amai yes, ProgramData is indicative of installing as Administrator. If it is has been working for you so far, then there’s no serious reason to reinstall. The disadvantages are minor inconveniences like having to elevate privileges when updating **base** and there being multiple package caches.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling miniconda, just to ensure convenience in the future. I still have an environments.txt file in a newly created .conda folder, but the envs are stored elsewhere. Is this normal? Also, does it matter that my Pythons are installed as admin? Would you reckon that it'd be easier if I kept everything installed without elevated perms? I'm so confused and I feel like it's best that I make everything simple so that I can work on other and more important things than worry about pathing everytime I want to work on something new.

Comment: @amai installing everything without elevated privileges is the typical procedure and, yes, it does tend to keep things simpler to work with. It is entirely normal for things to be in the `~/.conda` folder, such as `environments.txt`, which is what Conda uses to track environments, both named and those installed with `--prefix, -p` flag (i.e., outside the `envs_dirs` directories).